# How to output pagination 'P' and number only in expressionengine

Tags: expressionengine

I'm having issues with the variables like `path=group/template` that are generating an extra domain.

ie : hxxp://domain.com/hxxp://domain.com/template_group/template/

Pagination links are also rendered as :

hxxp://domain.com/hxxp://domain.com/template_group/template/P5

I'm using the Multi Lang Alt method (http://expressionengine.com/wiki/Multi_language_site_alternative/#Slight_modification_for_EE2), and I think this could be related to the problem.

I can find workarounds for the path, but I don't know how I can handle the pagination links.
If there were an option to just get the "Pxxx" returned, I could bypass this problem.

Can someone help on that point ?

Edit :

In /index.php I have :

```
$assign_to_config['site_index'] = 'http://domain.com/fr/';
    $assign_to_config['site_404'] = 'http://domain.com/fr/404/';
    $assign_to_config['global_vars'] = array(
        "cc"            => "", // added to custom fields in templates
        "country_code"  => "fr",
        "language"      => "french"
    );
```

In /en/index.php I have :

```
$assign_to_config['site_index'] = 'http://domain.com/en/';
$assign_to_config['site_404'] = 'http://domain.com/en/404/';
$assign_to_config['global_vars'] = array(
    "cc"            => "-en", // added to custom fields in templates
    "country_code"  => "en",
    "language"      => "english"
);
```

In /fr/index.php I have :

```
$assign_to_config['site_index'] = 'http://domain.com/fr/';
$assign_to_config['site_404'] = 'http://domain.com/fr/404/';
$assign_to_config['global_vars'] = array(
    "cc"            => "", // added to custom fields in templates
    "country_code"  => "fr",
    "language"      => "french"
);
```

Admin > General Configuration > site's index page is blank

and in  Admin > General Configuration > URL to the root directory is : http://domain.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is being caused by the fact that your overrides are specifying a domain for `site_index`. That should normally be `index.php` or blank if you're using mod_rewrite to hide it. The full URL should be saved as `site_url`. If you change those keys there's a good chance it will sort it:

```
$assign_to_config['site_url'] = 'http://domain.com/en/';
```

EE generates URLs by concatenating `site_url` and `site_index`, then it adds the path segments on the end. Both your URL and index values have domains in them, hence the weird `{path}` output.

Comment: Exactly - as Dom says and as I suspected, it's the variables declared that are giving EE a bit of misinformation as to what the root of your site is expected to be.

Comment: Yes, that's also what I suspected myself. I followed the instructions of the wiki without thinking about what I was doing. This is often a bad idea. Thanks.

Comment: Yep, a lot of the content on the wiki is outdated or specific to EE1. Hopefully a certain Area51 proposal will go through soon and we'll have a good go-to repository for up to date info on best practices/workflows.

Comment: I'd love to be in the loop when it comes out !

Comment: If you haven't already you can [register your interest here](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/46387/expressionengine?referrer=2jpk0ASgPUalETXKp3ZQQw2) and you'll be notified when the beta starts.

Answer (score 2):

Hmm. I suspect it's a variable you have set it your language-specific version of index.php (i.e. the copy of index.php that you placed in /en, for example).  Can you post what you have in index.php (both at the root of the site and in your /en/index.php) under $assign_to_config['global_vars'] (which is what that alternative method for multilingual has you set up)?  It seems like it may be that there is a variable that is at odds with what is declared in the control panel as the site root, which is resulting in the path variable being treated as a local link in its entirety rather than a proper link from the root of the domain.

What do you have in the control panel under Admin > General Configuration > Name of your site's index page? and what's in Admin > General Configuration > URL to the root directory of your site?